# AS3 multi-touch buttons error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multi-touch

I made two buttons and created action script below and then i published it and tested on my Galaxy3 but multi touch does not work. can anyone tell me what to do step by step? i am very very new to scrips and all that. probably some example file would be so so so nice!

import flash. ui. Multitouch;

import flash. ui. MultitouchInputMode;

Multitouch. inputMode = MultitouchInputMode. TOUCH_POINT;

Comment: You didn't provide enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [URL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-6ffb37601221e58cc29-8000.html), with all necessary information about touch, multitouch and gesture input.
Also, I extremely recommend you to check [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch) (multitouch gesture recognition library for Flash (ActionScript) development), check some examples and how to use [here](https://github.com/fljot/GestouchExamples)